# ORA-17162 error in jdbc

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, jboss

What is the ORA-17162 error (unsupported holdability value) in jdbc? we are getting this when using ojdbc7 with jboss 6.2 GA. The application was working fine when we were using ojdbc14. Once we switched to ojdbc7 the problems started arising.

Comment: Wow, that is a strange one.  Could not find anything relevant.

Comment: We still haven't figured anything relevant...may be ojdbc 7 won't work in linux? Ojdbc6 was a success though...